# Finding all combinations of a^2 + b^2 in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to find all combinations of x, where x = a^2 + b^2, and x is between 100 and 999.

So far i've got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 31 // given that 31^2 = 961

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    int poss_n[] = {0};

    for (int a=0; a <= MAX; a++){
        for (int b=0; b <= MAX; b++){
            if (a*a + b*b >= 100 && a*a + b*b <= 999){ 
                poss_n[i] = a*a + b*b;
                printf("%i\n", poss_n[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However it's giving only partially correct output, and also prematurely ends with segmentation fault 11:

> 100
>   1380405074
>   144
>   169
>   196
>   225
>   256
>   289
>   324
>   361
>   400
>   441
>   484
>   529
>   576
>   625
>   676
>   729
>   784
>   841
>   900
>   961
>   101
>   122
>   145
>   170
>   197
>   226
>   257
>   290
>   325
>   362
>   401
>   442
>   485
>   530
>   577
>   626
>   677
>   730
>   785
>   842
>   901
>   962
>   104
>   125
>   148
>   173
>   200
>   229
>   260
>   293
>   328
>   365
>   404
>   445
>   488
>   533
>   580
>   629
>   680
>   733
>   788
>   845
>   904
>   965
>   109
>   130
>   153
>   178
>   205
>   234
>   265
>   298
>   333
>   370
>   409
>   450
>   493
>   538
>   585
>   634
>   685
>   738
>   793
>   850
>   909
>   970
>   116
>   137
>   160
>   185
>   212
>   241
>   272
>   305
>   340
>   377
>   416
>   457
>   500
>   545
>   592
>   641
>   692
>   745
>   800
>   857
>   916
>   977
>   106
>   125
>   146
>   169
>   194
>   221
>   250
>   281
>   314
>   349
>   386
>   425
>   466
>   509
>   554
>   601
>   650
>   701
>   754
>   809
>   866
>   925
>   986
>   100
>   117
>   136
>   157
>   180
>   205
>   232
>   261
>   292
>   325
>   360
>   397
>   436
>   477
>   520
>   Segmentation fault: 11

What modifications should I make to my code?

**UPDATE**

Other than the the array issue, is there anything else wrong with my code? for instance it's still printing 100 as the first value which doesn't appear to be any combination of a^2 + b^2, even when b = 0.

**UPDATE 2**

Never mind, forgot a = 10, b = 0, which would be 100.

Comment: `poss_n[]` looks a bit short for what you're putting into it.

Comment: in addition to above comment use a temporary for the expression a^2+b^2.you'l save lot of multiplications.

Comment: print all results into file, then sort and cut.:-)

Comment: you should consider starting `b` from `a` each for: ` for (int b=a; b <= MAX; b++)` in order to avoid the same result twice.

Comment: @AntoineMathys No, either a or b can be 0.

Comment: As Koushik said You can use addition instead of multiplication counting squares. `(a+1)^2 - a^2 = 2a + 1`. So add `(a<<1) + 1` to a temp variable starting from 0. Similar can be applied to `b`. Also You could break for the inner loop if the sum is over 999. You do not need to check the remaining values. The value `b` could start from `(int)sqrt(100-a*a)` (or use a temp varable to keep track of the first `b` value) to reduce the number of inner loops.

Comment: `unsigned long` might be useful here...

Comment: @Koushik: *really*? You are suggesting - with a straight face - that the compiler will not do common subexpression elimination and code hoisting for the `a * a + b * b` expression and the programmer has to manually help it?

Comment: @NikBougalis true that it is not explicitly required(unless optimization is disabled) but can you guarantee that **all** compilers do that optimization implicitly?moreover lets be honest,do we really splatter expressions all over our code or the subject of those expression?either ways compiler can optimize the code considering which costs more.

Comment: @NikBougalis and code hoisting in the for loop? you really think hoisting is going to happen here in this piece of code?

Comment: Absolutely - the compiler can hoist the `a*a` out of the second loop, and can do common subexpression elimination for the `b*b` and the resulting `a*a + b*b` accordingly. Can I *guarantee* it? No, I'm sure you can find a non-optimizing compiler somewhere out there on the interwebs - or figure out how to disable optimizations on your compiler of choice. But any modern compiler can do these *trivial* (is there a stronger word I could use instead?) optimizations without even breaking a sweat. You can argue that code readability improves by using a variable - but don't argue it's an optimization.

Comment: @NikBougalis on gcc(hope this is modern enough) CSE kicks in from 01 level of optimization. Hoisting will not occur here because if CSE occurs then there will be no need for hoisting. whether its trivial(or not) compilers know best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
int poss_n[(MAX + 1) * (MAX + 1)] = {0};
```

This way you allocate enough memory to store your answers.

Comment: I think the size may need to be `(MAX + 1) * (MAX + 1)`

Comment: The upper count is at most (MAX+1)*(MAX+1)/2 due to symmetry. And min((M+1)*(M+1)/2, 999-100+1) given the other limit.

Comment: Thanks, it's a lot a better now, but still not giving a totally correct output. for instance, the first value it's printing is still 100, which doesn't seem to fit with any combination of a^2 + b^2.

Comment: For a=0, b=10, the combination (a^2+b^2) is 100

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you don't allocate place to save you results.

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 31 // given that 31^2 = 961

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    int poss_n[(MAX + 1) * (MAX + 1)] = {0}; //<<- Give it a size
    int result; //<<- Using this to reduce calculation of the value multiple times.

    for (int a=0; a <= MAX; a++){
        for (int b=0; b <= MAX; b++){
            result = a*a + b*b;
            if (result  >= 100 && result  <= 999){ 
                poss_n[i] = result ;
                printf("%i\n", result);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int poss_n[] = {0};
```

This will define array holding one element, leading to Segfault later when you will try to access element with index > 1

Answer (score 0):

As others already said you allocate too few space on stack. Stack goes from high addresses decreasing. So at first You overwrite the stack data corrupting it and then You reach the end of the stack and You try to write to a memory space not allocated to You, or not allocated at all. The CPU generates an exception and that's why the `Segmentation fault` error occurs.

Also You could allocate some memory with [malloc(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) on the heap and not on the stack, and when You found more result You can extend using realloc. It uses more system CPU resources, but reduces the memory overallocation.

On some un*ces You can also dynamically allocate memory on stack, using the [alloca(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca) function. It behaves very similar then `some_type array[some_value]`, but `some_value` can be calculated runtime and not compile time.

Also You can use [C++ STL containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/), like `vector` and `list` and You can push the found elements. The allocate memory segments automatically on the heap.

Some comments:
Addition can be used instead of multiplication counting squares. (a+1)^2 - a^2 = 2a + 1. So add (a<<1) + 1 to a temp variable starting from 0. Similar can be applied to b.
Also from the inner loop can be jumped with break if the sum is over 999. You do not need to check the remaining values.
The value b could start from (int)sqrt(100-a*a) (or use a temp varible to keep track of the first b value) to reduce the number of inner loops.

Comment: 1. There's no requirement that variables be allocated on a stack. 2. Stacks don't always grow down. 3. `malloc()` is not the right solution for someone who doesn't understand the requirement for size specification. 4. The question specifies C, not C++.

Comment: @mlp: Thank for Your comments! 1. Did I claim that? Usually the function local variables are allocated on stack. 2. You are absolutely right. But most of the systems I know, it does. 3. But it is a possible and commonly used solution worth to mention. Mainly for a beginner. 4. Mainly for a beginner it is more safe to use such containers as they do the memory handling automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it will work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 31 // given that 31^2 = 961

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    int poss_n[301];
int a,b;
    for (a=0; a <= MAX; a++){
        for (b=0; b <= MAX; b++){
            if (a*a + b*b >= 100 && a*a + b*b <= 999){ 
                poss_n[i] = a*a + b*b;
                printf("%i\t i = %d , a = %d , b = %d\n", poss_n[i],i,a,b);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers here, but none quite accurate.

Ff we assume that only unique output is printed out, loop should look like this (as Roee Gavirel stated):

```
for (int a=0; a <= MAX; a++){
    for (int b=a; b <= MAX; b++){
```

poss_n will hold this number of elements: `(32+(32-1)+(32-2)+..+1)=1/2*32*(32+1)`

So it should be defined as:

```
int elements = MAX+1;
int *poss_n = (int*)malloc ((1/2)*(elements)*(elements+1));
```

It will have more elements because of rule 100< value <999, but without that rule it will hold exact number of elements.